# Pure-managed C# SQLite client library

Tags: .net, sqlite, mono

I am looking for a client-side library to read/write to an SQLite3 database.

Requirements:

- Pure managed C#, does not use any `.dll` or `.so`
- No separate 32bit and 64 bit binaries
- Supports `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `CREATE`, `DELETE`, no need for more complex operations
- Free, ideally open source
- Works on any .NET and Mono

[csharp-sqlite](https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) does not work on Mono.

Comment: +1, since I need something like that as well. Just one note: on Windows you *will* need separate DLLs for 32 and 64 bit

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Do you a blog post or something saying that it is the official new repo? Many people have exported it to Github: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csharp-sqlite

Comment: OMG, it seems Github becomes the new DLL hell... Sorry, I don't know which one is the original

Comment: @ThomasWeller: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/764/where-is-csharp-sqlite-now-maintained